# Grab SelectedValue of Dropdownlist in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Creating a list of users that haven't updated their job title in a Gridview. I want the list to have a dropdown filled with all the possible title selections and a button next to the dropdown. Then a person can come in and change the title in the dropdown hit the button and its updated and removed from the list.

I have all of this the way I want it to look but I'm trying to figure out how to pass the SelectedValue of the dropdown box in that row to the code behind OnClick. As you can see below the closest I can get is pass the row number in the CommandArgument. Any suggestions how I can get the SelectedValue of the dropdown of that specific row to the OnClick?

**EDIT**: Maybe I should be using OnRowCommand instead of OnClick?

Looks like this currently:

```
John Doe | DropdownList  Button
Jane Doe | DropdownList  Button
Joe Doe | DropdownList  Button
Jeff Doe |  DropdownList  Button
```

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="TitleView" OnRowDataBound="TitleView_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Fullname" HeaderText="Fullname" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="input-append"><asp:DropDownList CssClass="span5" ID="TitleList" runat="server">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:Button ID="lbnView" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btn_Clicked" 
                                            CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>'></asp:Button></div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
public void bindTitleView()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT U.First + ' ' + U.Last as Fullname, U.UserID, T.Name FROM Employees U LEFT JOIN Titles T ON U.Title = T.ID WHERE U.Active = '1' AND U.Title = '92' ORDER BY Fullname ASC", conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(myDataSet);
            TitleView.DataSource = myDataSet;
            TitleView.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void TitleView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("TitleList");
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT ID, Name FROM Titles ORDER BY Name ASC", conn);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable myDataSet = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(myDataSet);
                ddl.DataSource = myDataSet;
                ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddl.DataValueField = "ID";
                ddl.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                String rowid = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
    }
```

**SOLUTION:** The answer I approved below worked for me once I added !IsPostBack to the Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bindTitleView();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like that:

```
protected void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int line = ((GridViewRow)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent).RowIndex;
    DropDownList drp = ((DropDownList)TitleView.Rows[line].FindControl("TitleList"));
    //Continue the method
}
```

Comment: When I try this I get 2 as the result everytime no matter what I select in the dropdown box. 2 happens to be the first value in the dropdown box, but even if I select a different selection the value always ends up being 2. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out, I'm missing the if (!IsPostBack) in my Page_Load when I bind the bindTitleView(). Oops!! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In your btn_click write the following code

```
protected void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button Sample = sender as Button;
    GridViewRow row = Sample.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    DropDownList drp = row.FindControl("TitleList") as DropDownList;
    //Now use drp.SelectedValue
    }
}
```

Let me know if this isnt what you are looking for.